# Genetic Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, beginner, ai, bioinformatics

I'm a new programmer, so any help is welcome. Preferably to make it faster, avoid heavy memory usage, and so on.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""
    This module is a frame work for a Genetic Algorithm.

    :param GenePool: See this documentation for how to use this module..
    :type GenePool: GenePool

    Author: Fernando Rodrigues dos Santos
"""
import random
import math
import pickle
import itertools
import sys


class GenePool():
    """"
        Place a gene in the  desired program using GenePool.nextGene().
        Place the genes variables(Gene.dna[id]) in the desired program.
        Reward good choices.
        Punish bad choices.

        Call GenePool.return_result() and pass the gene and the result to start the GA.

        After this the Genetic Algorithm will:
         - Save the top genes without modification and duplicate them(the amount is set by the elitism).

         - Remove the random genes to fit the population(the amount is set by the elitism).

         - Randomly choose genes based on their rank(roulette-wheel selection).

         - Cross-over the selected genes using the two-points cut method.(the amount of genes crossed is set by the
         cross_coefficient).

         - Finally it will apply the mutation to each gene(expect the top-rated).

         - It will repeat until find a convergence or stop if maxIteration is set.

        :param sample: The pattern of genes to be created.
        :type sample: list
        :param population: How many genes will be in the gene_pool.
        :type population: int
        :param cross_coefficient: The percentage of genes to do a random cross-over.
        :type cross_coefficient: float
        :param elitism: The amount of best-fitted genes to remain intact.
        :type elitism: float
        :param mutation: The chance that a dna will randomly mutate.
        :type mutation: float
        :param max_iterations: How many times it will try to find a convergence, if -1 it will run indefinitely(default).
        :type max_iterations: int
        :param save: File to save the pool.
        :type save: str
        """

    def __init__(self, sample, population, cross_coefficient=0.1, elitism=0.05, mutation=0.05, max_iterations=-1,
                 save="oldDNA.txt"):
        """
        The generated genes will be based on the sample;
         - bool, True or False
         - int, random number between 0 and1024
         - float, random number between 0.0 and 1.0

         - str, a combination of one letter(a-z) and one number(0-9). E.gene: "a1", "b2", "c2"..."z9".

        Population is the size of the gene_pool.

        See more in the class documentation.
        """

        self.sample = sample
        self.population = population
        self.genes = {}
        self.new_gene_pool = []
        self.cross_coefficient = cross_coefficient
        self.elitism = elitism
        self.mutation = mutation
        self.max_iterations = max_iterations
        self.current_iteration = 0
        self.total_result = 0
        self.calls = -1
        self.save = save
        self.convergence = False
        self.new_genes()

    def new_genes(self):
        while len(self) != self.population:
            dna = []
            for chromosome in self.sample:
                if chromosome == bool:
                    dna.append(bool(random.getrandbits(1)))
                elif chromosome == int:
                    dna.append(random.randint(0, 2 ** 10))
                elif chromosome == float:
                    dna.append(random.random())
            gene = Genes(self, '%i' % (len(self) + 1), dna)
            self[gene.name] = gene

    def next_gene(self):
        """
        :returns: A gene to be used.
        :rtype: Genes

        """
        self.calls += 1
        if self.calls >= self.population:
            self.calls = 0
            self.start_genetic_algorithm()

        return self[self.calls]

    def replace_gene(self, old_gene, new_dna, result, rank):
        new_gene = Genes(self, old_gene.name, new_dna, result=result, rank=rank)
        self[old_gene.name] = new_gene
        self.new_gene_pool.append(new_gene)

    def rated_list(self, cut):
        rated_list = sorted([(gene.rank, gene) for _, gene in self.genes.iteritems()])[::-1]

        selected = int(math.ceil(len(self) * self.elitism))
        top_genes = rated_list[0:selected]
        mid_genes = rated_list[selected:len(self) - selected]

        genes = None
        if cut == 'top':
            genes = top_genes
        elif cut == 'mid':
            genes = mid_genes

        return genes

    def duplicate_top(self):
        top_genes = self.rated_list('top')
        for gene in top_genes:
            gene = gene[1]
            gene.rank /= 2
            gene.result /= 2
            new_gene = Genes(self, "%i" % (len(self) + 1), gene.dna, gene.result, gene.rank)
            self[new_gene.name] = new_gene
            self.new_gene_pool.append(new_gene)
            gene.lock = True
            self.new_gene_pool.append(gene)

    def mutate_mid_genes(self):
        for gene in self:
            new_dna = []
            for chromosome in gene.dna:
                rand = random.random()
                if rand <= self.mutation:
                    if type(chromosome) == bool:
                        new_dna.append(bool(random.getrandbits(1)))
                    if type(chromosome) == int:
                        new_dna.append(random.randint(0, 2 ** 10))
                    if type(chromosome) == float:
                        new_dna.append(random.random())
                else:
                    new_dna.append(chromosome)
            gene.dna = new_dna

    def cross_genes(self):
        ranks = [gene.rank for gene in self.genes.itervalues()]
        min_rank = min(ranks)
        max_rank = max(ranks)
        max_tries = 0
        while len(self.new_gene_pool) < self.population or max_tries == 100:
            max_tries += 1
            gene1 = None
            gene2 = None
            while gene1 is None or gene2 is None:
                rand = random.uniform(min_rank, max_rank)
                gene1 = [gene for gene in self.genes.itervalues() if gene.rank >= rand and not gene.lock and gene
                    .rank != 1]
                if gene1:
                    gene1 = random.choice(gene1)
                    pass
                else:
                    gene1 = None
                rand = random.uniform(min_rank, max_rank)
                gene2 = [gene for gene in self.genes.itervalues() if gene.rank >= rand and not gene.lock and gene !=
                                                                     gene1 and gene.rank != 1]
                if gene2:
                    gene2 = random.choice(gene2)
                else:
                    gene2 = None
            self.crossover(gene1, gene2)
        for gene in self:
            gene.lock = False

    def crossover(self, gene1, gene2):
        """Two-Point cross-over"""
        cross_point1, cross_point2 = None, None
        while not cross_point2 and not cross_point1:
            cross_point1 = random.randint(0, len(gene1))
            cross_point2 = random.randint(0, len(gene1))
            if cross_point1 == cross_point2 or cross_point1 > cross_point2:
                cross_point1, cross_point2 = None, None
        new_dna1 = gene1[:cross_point1] + gene2[cross_point1:cross_point2] + gene1[cross_point2:]
        new_dna2 = gene2[:cross_point1] + gene1[cross_point1:cross_point2] + gene2[cross_point2:]
        result = (gene1.result + gene2.result) / 2
        rank = (gene1.rank + gene2.rank) / 2
        self.replace_gene(gene1, new_dna1, result, rank)
        self.replace_gene(gene2, new_dna2, result, rank)

    def return_result(self, gene, result):
        """Return here the gene, it's fitness result. Set force to True to run the GA in the gene_pool
        :param gene: The gene which was run.
        :type gene: Genes
        :param result: The fitness result.
        :type result: int
        """
        gene.result += result
        self.total_result += gene.result

    def test_convergence(self, print_result=False):
        if print_result:
            pro = 0
            con = 0
            for gene1, gene2 in itertools.combinations(self.genes.itervalues(), 2):
                if gene1.dna == gene2.dna:
                    pro += 1
                else:
                    con += 1
            cc = (con + 1) / (pro + 1)
            print "Converged rate: 1:%i" % cc

        if self.convergence or self.current_iteration == self.max_iterations:
            for gene in self:
                print "Convergence Found: \nGene: %s\nDNA: %s" % (gene.name, gene.dna)
                sys.exit("End of the line")

    def reset_genes(self):
        for gene in self:
            gene.rank = 0
            gene.result = 0
            gene.lock = False
        self.total_result = 0

    def save_results(self):
        f = open(self.save, 'w')
        pickle.dump(self, f)
        f.close()

    def update_result(self):
        self.total_result = 0
        self.genes = {}
        for gene in self.new_gene_pool:
            new_gene = Genes(self, '%i' % (len(self.genes) + 1), gene.dna)
            self.genes[new_gene.name] = new_gene
        self.new_gene_pool = []

    def start_genetic_algorithm(self):
        [gene.update_rank() for gene in self.genes.itervalues()]
        self.current_iteration += 1
        self.duplicate_top()
        self.cross_genes()
        self.update_result()
        self.test_convergence(print_result=True)
        self.mutate_mid_genes()
        # self.saveResults()
        return self.convergence

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if type(item) == str:
            return self.genes[item]
        if type(item) == int:
            return self[sorted(self.genes)[item]]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.genes[key] = value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.genes)


class Genes():
    """
    A gene which mutates based on it's gene_pool settings

    :param gene_pool: Where all genes are stored and the GA will run
    :type gene_pool: GenePool
    :param dna: The core of the gene, it's based on the sample set on the gene_pool.
    :type dna: list
    :param result: The current fitness result of the gene.
    :type result: int
    :param rank: The result from 0.0 to 1.0 of the gene in the gene_pool.
    :type rank: float
    """

    def __init__(self, gene_pool, name, dna, result=0, rank=0):
        """should be instantiated by genePool.newGenes()"""
        self.name = name
        self.gene_pool = gene_pool
        self.dna = dna
        self.result = result
        self.rank = rank
        self.lock = False

    def update_rank(self):
        self.rank = self.result / float(self.gene_pool.total_result)
        return self.rank

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dna)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.dna[item]

gene_pool = GenePool([int] * 3, 100)

while True:
    gene = gene_pool.next_gene()
    dna = gene.dna
    result = 1
    if dna[0] <= 100:
        result += 10
        if dna[0] == 100:
            result += 100
    if dna[1] >= 200:
        result += 10
        if dna[1] == 200:
            result += 100
    if 100 <= dna[2] <= 200:
        result += 10
        if dna[2] == 150:
            result += 100

    if dna[0] == 100 and dna[1] == 200 and dna[2] == 150:
        gene_pool.convergence = True

    gene_pool.return_result(gene, result)
```

Comment: Is there a specific performance issue you've noticed? Have you tried anything to make it faster and/or reduce memory footprint? Any profiling? Do you have an example we can run?

Comment: If I use a population of 100 and my the lenght of the dna is 10 it takes around 30 seconds for a calculation.

I'm trying to shrink uses of for loops and the like, but I'm not very used to any other ways of reducing performance hits.

Haven't done any test on memory. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You should start by profiling to determine where exactly the time is being taken: see [the `profile` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). You can also do memory profiling, although not from the standard library; see e.g. [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).

Comment: As a side note: Your code doesn't follow [PEP 8](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You can use [`pep8.py`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) (and `autopep8.py`), which is also included in [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), to check where you don't conform.

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed the commented out remove_to_fit method but had forgot to remove when I I was calling. It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you should do is not place code you always want run at the lowest level in the file, you should place it in a function called `main()` and call `main()` with `if __name__ == "__main__":`.  This will help you when you start creating modules and importing them, and is [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Other than this, your code is very neat, and it is good that it follows PEP-8 standards.  I cannot comment on the performance as I do not have Python in my system at the time of writing this.